# Trying to understand the difference between static and dynamic scoping in this C program

Tags: c, dynamic, static, scoping

So I am just trying to take a look at this little bit of code in C. Basically I am trying to learn how to read / determine the differences when using static and dynamic scoping and how the output will be different depending on which I am using. I have picked 3 lines and was gonna just try to compare the symbol table for static vs dynamic but don't know where to begin.

```
# include <stdio.h>            
int a = 101; 
char b = 'z'; int q(char b) {
  int a = 89;
  printf ("%c\n",a);      
  printf("%d\n",b);        // line 7
  return a;
}
void p() {
  double b = 2.6;
  printf("%c\n",a);
  printf("%f\n",b);               // line 13 
  a = q(a);
}
int main() {
  char a = 'L'; 
  printf("%c\n",b);      // line 17 
  p();
  return 0;
}
```

Code runs fine I just am not sure if I can choose to use static vs dynamic scoping or how. Really just being able to understand whats going on is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 7, `b` refers to the argument to `q()`; it is the nearest declaration of `b`.

At line 13, `b` refers to the local variable.

At line 17, `b` refers to the global variable; there is no other candidate to use.

Comment: so if I am analyzing statically 
my print out for 
line 7 will be z
line 13 will be 2.6
line 17 will be z again?

Comment: No. The letter printed at 7 will be `'e'` (aka 101) because that’s the value in `a` when `q()` is called, isn’t it? Your values for lines 23 and 17 are correct.